# Streaming Audio Not Working on Android

Tags: android, iis-7, html5-audio

I have a simple web page that is using the HTML 5 audio tag for streaming.  I've set up an IIS7 rewrite rule so that browsers can't directly download the MP3 file, but it can still be streamed via the audio control.  This works fine on my desktop (Chrome 37.0.2062.124 m) but not on my Android device (Samsung Galaxy S5).  I can't download the file on Android but I can't stream it either.  When I disable the rewrite rule, the streaming works fine on both devices but of course the file can be downloaded directly as well.

Here is my page:

```
    <div>
        <h3>
            Audio
        </h3>

        <audio controls="controls" preload="auto">
            <source src="audio.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
        </audio>
    </div>
```

Here is my web.config:

```
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Prevent MP3 Hotlinking" enabled="true">
                <match url=".*\.(mp3)$" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_REFERER}" pattern="^$" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{HTTP_REFERER}" pattern="http://www.example.com/.*" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="http://www.example.com" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

EDIT:
I've set up my phone to use my PC as a proxy so I can use Fiddler2 to monitor the traffic.  Some strange things are happening.

From my PC (which works), the browser initates a GET of the MP3 file and correctly receives an HTTP 206 response.  From my phone (which doesn't work), it first issues a GET to the mp3 file, receives a 206 response, but then immediately initiates another GET of the mp3 file without an HTTP_REFERER, which of course causes it to fail due to the URL rewrite.  I'm not sure what else I can do, is this simply a problem with the Chrome browser on my phone?

Answer (score 0):

Is your server doing any redirects? If so, are you following those redirects in the Android client? If not, that may be your issue.

Comment: Nope, no redirects.  It's just an HTML page that directly links to the mp3 file located in the same server, same directory.

Answer (score 0):

I may have figured this out. Try adding the following to your conditions:

`<add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="iPhone" negate="true" />`.

Change the iPhone user agent to whatever is appropriate for your Galaxy S5. This worked for me, although I'm not doing a redirect, but a custom response, such as "file not found." I'm also not using an empty referrer pattern as you are.

I found this on [the Apple Support site](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4506007?tstart=0)